# Only able to get /article/1/ to load. /article/2/ displays a 404

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

Each page in /articles/x/ represents one article, each article has its own article content which is in the ArticleContent model which is structure like

| id | tag | css_id | css_class | content | article_id (foreign key that points to Article Table) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | p |  |  | blab la | 1 |
| 2 | p |  |  | bahaofs | 2 |

actual database has more records for multiple article_ids

loading /article/1/ works exactly as expected with article content

ArticleContent Model

```
class ArticleContent(models.Model):

    article = models.ForeignKey('Article', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    order = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
    tag = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    css_id = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    css_class = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    extra = models.TextField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    content = models.TextField(max_length=2000, blank=True)
```

Article Model

```
class Article(models.Model):

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.title

    title = models.TextField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    preview = models.TextField(max_length=500)
    hasimage = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='articles/static/articles/images', blank=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True)
    url = models.TextField(blank=True)
    alt = models.TextField(max_length=1000, blank=True)
```

urls.py

```
app_name = 'article'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('articles/<int:pk>/', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='article_detail'),
]
```

views

```
class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    
    model = ArticleContent
    template_name = 'articles/article_detail.html'

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        article_content = ArticleContent.objects.filter(article_id=self.kwargs['pk'])
        return article_content

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Call the base implementation first to get a context
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        # Add in settings
        context['ordered_article_content'] = self.get_queryset()
        context['kwargs'] = self.kwargs['pk']
        context['is_header_on'] = True
        context['is_footer_on'] = True
        context['header_links'] = HeaderLinks.objects.all()
        context['footer_links'] = FooterLinks.objects.all()
        return context
```

article_detail.html template

```
{% extends "./base.html" %}

{% block content %}

    {% for x in ordered_article_content %}
        <{{ x.tag }} id="{{ x.css_id }}" class="{{ x.css_class }}" {{ x.extra }} >{{ x.content }}</{{ x.tag }}>

    {% endfor %}

    {{ kwargs }}

{% endblock %}
```

Error for article/2/
Page not found (404)
No article content found matching the query

Accessing article_id = 2 works on the articles/1/ page, so I think the problem is something to do with article/2+/.  I have no idea why, because I don't specifically reference a particular article_id anywhere I think.  Wondering if this is something to do with how django does views that I'm just not understanding.

I'm just trying to get article/2+/ to render the same way article/1/ does

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should implement `get_object`: `get_queryset` is filtered additionally on the primary key in a `DetailView`, so:

from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

```
class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = ArticleContent
    template_name = 'articles/article_detail.html'

    def get_object(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return get_object_or_404(ArticleContent, lemons_id=self.kwargs['pk'])

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Call the base implementation first to get a context
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['kwargs'] = self.kwargs['pk']
        context['is_header_on'] = True
        context['is_footer_on'] = True
        context['header_links'] = HeaderLinks.objects.all()
        context['footer_links'] = FooterLinks.objects.all()
        return context
```

The item will be passed to the template as `object`, so you render it *without* a `for` loop with:

```
<{{ object.tag }} id="{{ object.css_id }}" class="{{ object.css_class }}" {{ object.extra }} >{{ object.content }}</{{ object.tag }}>
```

But likely what you want is a `ListView`, so:

```
class MyListView(generic.ListView):
    model = ArticleContent
    template_name = 'articles/article_detail.html'
    context_object_name = 'ordered_article_content'

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        article_content = ArticleContent.objects.filter(article_id=self.kwargs['pk'])
        return article_content

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Call the base implementation first to get a context
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        # Add in settings
        context['kwargs'] = self.kwargs['pk']
        context['is_header_on'] = True
        context['is_footer_on'] = True
        context['header_links'] = HeaderLinks.objects.all()
        context['footer_links'] = FooterLinks.objects.all()
        return context
```

Comment: Getting an error for retrieving multiple objects with get_object_or_404.  MultipleObjectsReturned at /dynsearch/articles/2/
get() returned more than one ArticleContent -- it returned 6!  The ArticleContent table has multiple records attached to each article.

Comment: @cantrip: then you use a `ListView`, as specified at the bottom. You also should *not* assign it to the context itself: the `ListView` is already doing that: you specify the name with `context_object_name`.

Comment: Thanks, the ListView works, somehow I didn't see that in your answer, my mistake.